# D3 Family tree zoom implementation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Basically i wish to implement a zoom behavior to my family tree like in this example here http://bl.ocks.org/sgruhier/1d692762f8328a2c9957

I've added the call function to where im creating the svg canvas but it does nothing, am i missing something ? Thanks in advance

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fam tree</title>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>     
        <style>

            body, html {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            svg {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            .link {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #ccc;
                stroke-width: 1.5px;
            }
            div.tooltip {
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
                width: 200px;
                height: 30px;
                padding: 8px;
                font: 16px sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                background: #ffff99;
                border: solid 1px #aaa;
                border-radius: 8px;
                pointer-events: none;
                background-color: rgba(0,128,128,0.5);
                overflow: hidden;
                transition: .5s ease
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="viz"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            //JSON 
            var treeData = {"name" : "Steve", "lname" : "Forester", "children" : [
                    {"name" : "Anna", "lname" : "Woods" }, 
                    {"name" : "Boris", "lname" : "Vladimirov" }, 
                    {"name" : "Clint", "lname" : "Eastwood", "children": [

                            {"name" : "Sheldon", "lname" : "Morris" }, 
                            {"name" : "Bert", "lname" : "Jefferson" }
                        ]} 
                ]};

            // Create a svg canvas
            var vis = d3.select("#viz")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", "1500")
            .attr("height", "1000")
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
            }))
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100, 100)"); // shift everything to the right

            // Add tooltip div
            var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 1e-6);

            // Create a tree "canvas"
            var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([1200, 500]);

            var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal();

            // Preparing the data for the tree layout, convert data into an array of nodes
            var nodes = tree.nodes(treeData);
            // Create an array with all the links
            var links = tree.links(nodes);

            var link = vis.selectAll("pathlink")
            .data(links)
            .enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", diagonal)

            var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })

            // Hexagon img
            node.append("svg:image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "prva.png")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100)
            .attr("x", -50)
            .attr("y", -30)
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mousemove", function(d){mousemove(d);})
            .on("mouseout", mouseout)
            .attr("fill","red")
            .attr("r", 5.5);

            function mouseover() {
                div.transition()
                .duration(300)
                .style("opacity", 1);
                d3.select(this).attr("xlink:href", "vtora.png");

            }

            function mousemove(d) {
                div
                .text(" Name:" + ' ' + d.name + ' ' + d.lname)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");

            }

            function mouseout() {
                div.transition()
                .duration(300)
                .style("opacity", 1e-6);
                d3.select(this).attr("xlink:href", "prva.png");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at your code. You don't have any variable named `svg`. Thus, it should be `vis.attr("transform", "translate...`.

Comment: I have no clue how could i have missed that.. It works perfectly, thank you kindly =]